# Problem with slugfy with Vietnamese language

Tags: javascript, npm

I am using module slugfy from npm to create a slug URL. However, when I use it with some special string, I have unsatisfied results. For example, when I using it in the Vietnamese language.

```
const slugify = require('slugify');
console.log(slugify(Đồ gia dụng));
```

It's result

```
djo-gia-dung
```

And I want it to be

```
do-gia-dung
```

Please give me the solution to deal with it. Thank you for your attention

Comment: have you tried to specify the locale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the language to slugify, in the options

Try this

```
slugify('Đồ gia dụng', {locale: 'vi'})
```

Comment: @Đoàn Đức Bảo could you please mark this as solved, if this solved your issue?